# Error: Firebase reCAPTCHA placeholder element must be empty

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, firebase, authentication

I am using firebase authentication with phone number, and that requires Recaptcha verification. I had initially used the normal visible recaptcha, and that worked fine, but a need came in to make the recaptcha an invisible one.
I used Firebase's documentations on this and here's my code below:

```
const generateRecaptcha = () => {
   window.recaptchaVerifier = new RecaptchaVerifier(
      "signin_btn",
      {
        size: "invisible",
        callback: (response) => {
          onSignInSubmit();
        },
      },
      auth
    );
  };

const onSignInSubmit = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    const q = query(doc(db, "users", phone));
    const querySnapshot = await getDoc(q);
    console.log("Snapshot", querySnapshot.exists());
if (
  phone === "" ||
  password === "" ||
  repeatPassword === "" ||
  lastname === "" ||
  firstname === ""
) {
  setLoading(false);
  setErrors("Please fill the needed fields.");
} else if (password !== repeatPassword) {
  setErrors("Passwords do not match.");
  setLoading(false);
} else if (querySnapshot.exists()) {
  setErrors(
    "This phone number already exists on the server. Please try another number."
  );
  setLoading(false);
} else {
  setErrors("Complete ReCaptcha to get verification code");
  generateRecaptcha();
  let appVerifier = window.recaptchaVerifier;
  console.log("Did we get here?");
  signInWithPhoneNumber(auth, phone, appVerifier)
    .then((confirmationResult) => {
      console.log("We got here..!!");
      window.confirmationResult = confirmationResult;
      setLoading(false);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
    });
}


 };
```

I end up getting this error though

[image: My Error message image]

Please I need help on this issue.

Comment: Having same issue, nothing seem to be found on the internet. Google Cloud collective gives zero fcks about problems users are facing while using their products.